# Is it a way to use other page objects from another page called by ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, object

I'm coding a plugin for a web browser game (which isn't mine), and I have a little question.
In a HTML page, there are differents defined JS variables, objects and array of objects which I'm trying to call with Ajax.

What I did until now, it's to use regex to target the variables then use JSON.parse. But it's really boring, so is there a better way ?

In the original page, there is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var something = [{"id":1,"name":"Luke","class":"Jedi"},{"id":2,"name":"Sidious","class":"Sith"}];
var token = "02sdf4039FD4389fdli3409";
var thing = "";
var object = {AnotherObject};
...
</script>
```

What I do actually :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'otherpage.php',
        success: function(data) {
             var myVar = data.match(/var something = (.*)/)[1].replace(';','');
             console.log(JSON.parse(myVar));
             // returns 
             //0: {id: 1, name: "Luke", class: "Jedi"}
             //1: {id: 2, name: "Sidious", class: "Sith"}
        }
});
```

It works yeah, but it's a patch-up job.
Is there something using javascript where I just could get ALL the variables from the called page ? Because there are many and it's boring to use regex/json.parse for all of them.

I hope i'm clear, sorry for my english. I tried to find a solution everywhere, and there is nothing. But maybe i'm not specific enough during my search.

Thank you

PS: My "plugin" is a Userscript using Tampermonkey, so I don't have any control on the originals files.

Comment: You could use an AST tree, first use a HTML parser to extract the script, and then with this script use a Javascript AST parser.  This would be much more reliable that using regular expressions.  You can go here -> https://astexplorer.net/ to play with different AST parsers.

Comment: Well, I really don't know how it works, I tried a little bit to understand with your link, and it seems really more complicated than what i do until now :S
I'm maybe just too bad, it's possible ^^'